# Is possible to write map reduce jobs in Java for google compute engine?

Tags: java, mapreduce, google-compute-engine

As the sample map reduce jobs are written in Python is it possible to write a job in Java and submit it google compute engine for map reduce ?

Comment: Did you try Googling this? A cursory search says yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which sample map-reduce jobs are you referring to? Are you planning to run them on Hadoop? If so, yes you can write jobs in a number of languages, including Java.

If you're asking if Hadoop can run on Compute Engine, the answer is also yes! :)

Lots of details here:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hadoop/